# Office word editor control for WinForms Applications

Tags: c#, .net, vba, ms-word, winforms-interop

I know that this question may be very old and classic but, I am trying to find a free and good word editor control to be embedded into my application for educational purpose, so I googled and tried a lot of editors and methods like using `RichTextBox` control and fill the RTF value with my word document data and it was displayed into the `RichTextBox` but without any editing capabilities that exist in the real Word application.

I just need some of the editing capabilities that are exist in the word not all of them, so I decided to build my own word editor but actually I can't find a good way to start that and I don't have that experience, Any Ideas?

What I did until now is very basic and I need to know for example how to add a new method to attach word document to my editor so I need to do something like

```
wordEditor1.Word = {Path of word document}
```

and this step should show the document inside my editor with all styles and formats just like opening any word document inside word application.

Also I need to add capability of applying paragraph style or character style on the selected paragraph, so I think that I need to add methods for characters or paragraphs like

```
selectedParagraph.Style = {name of style in word or name of selected style form styles pane}
```

Finally I need to allow user to run macros on the opened document and I know that this may be the hardest step, so I just need some ideas to redirect me to the best way of how to do that.

What I did till now is something like

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoStyle
{
    public partial class WordEditor : RichTextBox
    {
        public WordEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public object Word
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that this question may help others like me who is newbie and has a lack of experience, so I appreciate you comments and efforts.

Comment: [ScintillaNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jacobslusser.ScintillaNET/) has a lot of capabilities.Perhaps, an HTML editor control combined with [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) as converter might be helpful.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. I think it is great that you want to “create” a Word type editor using a `RichTextBox` in a win forms project. And I do not want to dissuade you from attempting this, however, as you said you are a _“newbie,”_ then  creating a Word type editor even with a very limited functionality… is NOT going to be trivial. Is there some reason you want to re-invent the wheel? If the user is already familiar with Word and you obviously have Word on the machine, is there some reason you don’t want the user to use the Word App?

Comment: @JohnG I need to add another capabilities that are not exist in the word like opening 3 or 4 word documents in a something like a gridview and changing in one document should affect others simultaneously and the user should see that happens for learning purpose and a lot of other options that I am planning extend my editor with in the future, so I decided to create my own editor to be easy to extend it with another options. finally I would like to thank you for your comment but because I am newbie so I need to learn to be professional  in one day.

Comment: @AxelKemper I know about ScintillaNet but as I told you I need to edit inside the opened word document and save it as a word document so it's a good idea to convert word to html and open it inside html editor but it will be limited for viewing the document and also how could I save the html document as docx file again after the user finish his edits?

Comment: @AxelKemper actually your comment lighten up an idea to me, I will save the document to html from the word interop and will view it and then after the user finish I will save it again to docx from interop. just I need to find a way of how can I run some macros on the html doc or apply styles?

Comment: @Myogeo … I admire your confidence to be a _”newbie”_ and feel it will only take you a day to be a _”professional.”_ … I say go for it; it will be challenging for sure. Unfortunately, I stick by my original comment that your question is too broad for SO and needs more focus.

Comment: @JohnG Sorry I mean to say in someday not only one day for sure :) I am sorry for misunderstanding